# Swift 3 Generic infix operator error

Tags: ios, generics, operator-overloading, swift3

In the process of updating a project from Xcode 7 to 8, I'm facing a problem.

There is a generic `infix` operator which handles constraints on `UIView`s.

Here is the operator's definition:

```
precedencegroup constPrecedence {
  associativity: left
  higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

infix operator >>>- : constPrecedence

@discardableResult
func >>>- <T: UIView> (left: (T, T), block: (inout ConstraintInfo) -> ()) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
  var info = ConstraintInfo()
  block(&info)
  info.secondAttribute = info.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute ? info.attribute : info.secondAttribute
  
  let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: left.1,
                                      attribute: info.attribute,
                                      relatedBy: info.relation,
                                      toItem: left.0,
                                      attribute: info.secondAttribute,
                                      multiplier: 1,
                                      constant: info.constant)
  constraint.identifier = info.identifier
  left.0.addConstraint(constraint)
  return constraint
}
```

now, upon using the operator, I'm getting an error I don't understand:

```
   for attribute: NSLayoutAttribute in [.left, .right, .top, .bottom] {
      (view, self) >>>- {
        $0.attribute = attribute
      }
    }
```

[image: infix operator error]

I have tested with non-generic function too, it will still complain about the block's type.

Any idea?

P.S.: I'm not the original author of the code, I'm trying to updated the code for a PR and to change the syntax will impact too much code.

Comment: Please can you post a [mcve]

Comment: It's not too much of a code, you can easily verify this anywhere. I thought I've had provided enough evidence. What else do you need?

Comment: I have already tried (and failed) to reproduce this in Xcode 8 beta 6 (I assume [this](https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding) is the GitHub project you're referring to?). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/e44bd25823d24dea068e0498fa1cef4b) for an example of it compiling. Perhaps try cleaning your build folder?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have cleaned and removed derived data and everything. I have tested your gist, it works as expected, but in the main project. I'm guessing a setting is messed up. I have to investigate build setting of the project now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a `return` call at the end of the code block passed to the operator. It seems like Swift 3.0 compiler cannot infer code block to be a closure without `return`. As mentioned in the question's comments, the original operator should work fine with a new Swift 3.0 project, but converting the project from older Swift versions seems to break the operator somehow.

Any way This is the correct usage of the operator now and it works fine:

```
 for attribute: NSLayoutAttribute in [.left, .right, .top, .bottom] {
      (view, self) >>>- {
        $0.attribute = attribute
        return
      }
    }
```

P.S.: I have been doing this fix before but I was getting a weird `Segmentation Fault error 11` after a few of errors' been fixed and I wasn't aware of the reason. Turns out, Xcode could not handle some of the closure types and segmentation fault was happening. Adding `return` call to ALL places where the operator was being used solved the problem.

I would be happy to discuss the reason and a better solution with any interested developer.